# After the first 30 minutes of water thawing my 20 pound turkey, I discovered water had leaked into the wrapper. What can I do to save it?

Tags: water, turkey

I had my 20 pound turkey defrosting for two days in the refrigerator and just began the cold water thaw. After 30 minutes I came back to change out the water and discovered water had leaked into the original wrapper, how should I proceed, it’s still quite frozen. Should I rinse and put in new plastic bag and continue sink thaw or place in refrigerator as is, hoping for the best?

Answer (score 8):

It's not a problem that some water leaked into the bag.  You could leave as is or remove the plastic altogether.  This is not a safety issue or a quality issue. Temperature is the most important variable to control risk.  You will want to be careful about potential cross-contamination when changing out the water...avoid splashing. Before cooking, just use some paper towel, or a cloth towel that you will use for only this purpose then wash, to dry off the bird.